# How does the $\epsilon - \delta$ actually ensure that $L$ is the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Quickly writing out the definition,
$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ iff $ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \ s.t. \ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$

Here is what I think it means,

For any small distance $\epsilon >0$, I have to find at least one deleted $\delta$ nbd of $a$ for which the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ is even less than $\epsilon$ if every $x$ is taken from the deleted nbd of $a$.

This is just translating that expression into simple English. The thing is that, I "understand" the "expression" but I just can't see why that would imply or tell us that $L$ is indeed the limit of the function $f(x)$ at $x=a$

Again, please note that, I don't need an explanation for the mathematical expression, I need help understanding **why** would that imply $L$ is the limit. What is the **logic** here?

Edit: I understand limit to be a particular specific value that the function approaches when $x$ approaches $a$. It does not assert that $f(x)$ is $L$ at $x=a$ i.e $f(a)= L$. $f(a)$ might as well not be defined for all we care.

Comment: It may depend on what do **you** understand by "limit of function", but your wording of limit definition says it all: you can approach arbitrarily close to $\;L\;$ by means of values $\;f(x)\;$ of the function as long as you take values of the free variable $\;x\;$ "close enough" to $\;a\;$ ...

Comment: You should add what in your view *is* a limit of a function. Then this view can be criticized or (if your view is okay) it can be made clear why the definition mentioned in your question ensures that we are indeed dealing with a limit.

Comment: @DonAntonio good point, I understand, limit of a function is a value that $f(x)$ approaches when $x$ approaches $a$. The problem is, I'm just not able to put everything together.

Comment: @drhab edited! Done!

Comment: The definition doesn't give you a value for $L$. It's just a definition. Given $f, a$, if you can find an $L$ that satisfies the definition, then whatever $L$ might be is what I call the limit. By definition. It just so happens to agree with your "approaching" intuition.

Comment: @JuliusL33t yes that is literally what I just said in my explanation. Of course we aren't finding $L$. We are "proving" that $L$ is the limit. You may have misread my explanation.

Comment: @William I don't understand what is unclear. If you understand that $L$ is the value that $f$ approches as $x \to a$ (which may or may not be equal to $f(a)$), and you understand that this is exactly what is captured by the definition, then what is unclear? Note that all the answers so far say very similar things. What are you unhappy about?

Comment: Can you write something about what you think the difference between your favored concept of limit and the usual definition is? You don't seem to have pointed to any situation where you would like the definition to behave differently.

Comment: About your last paragraph starting with "Edit": the meaning of a limit is given in the definition and when you say "$f(x) $ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $a$" you just refer to a set of logical inferences mentioned in the definition and nothing else. It is not as if there is some mental process of assigning values to $x$ near $a$ and as a result values of $f(x) $ are near $L$. It takes a little time to get used to the fact that limit is all about logical inferences (dealing with inequalities related to values of a function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ and prove that there is $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$. That can be rewritten in the form $f(x)\in (L-\varepsilon, L + \varepsilon)$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$. This tells you that if the limit at $a$ exists, it should be in the interval $[L-\varepsilon, L + \varepsilon]$. Now, if you prove the same thing for every $\varepsilon>0$, it tells you that the limit at $a$ should be in

$$\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}[L-\varepsilon, L + \varepsilon] = \{L\}.$$

So we say $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$.

Note that this intuition is basically squeeze theorem (and that's why I use segment instead of open interval).

Comment: This is what I was trying to get at in my answer, and you’ve said it much cleaner here. +1

Comment: That is a sweet explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By limit, let say we mean that the closer I am to $a$ then the closer I am to $L$. 
The understanding should be that I could get as close as I want to $L$ and that I at some point a don't go too far away from $L$.

To understand the definition, you might want to take the wiewpoint of the limit and not the viewpoint of the variable.

Assume you have ordered a cab and you can see on your famous app that the cab is moving towards you. Because streets might not be perfectly regular, the cab do some detour, however it does come closer and closer.
So you hope that if you wait enough time he will get closer that 100m, closer than 10m, clsoer that 1m,...

Answer (score 0):

Well, one approach would be to consider some other point, $R$, and show that $f$ has to eventually always be closer to $L$ than to $R$.

Assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$, and let $R$ be any point other than $L$. Now, take any $\varepsilon$ that satisfies $0<\varepsilon<\frac{|L-R|}{2}$. This ensures that

> $\text{if } |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon \text{, then } |f(x)-L|<|f(x)-R|.$

By the definition of the limit, there exists some $\delta>0$ where if $|x-a|<\delta$, that is, if $x$ is close enough to $a$, then $f(x)$ must always be closer to $L$ than to $R$.

But we can do this for every point $R$ that isn’t $L$! We can always force $f(x)$ to be closer to $L$ than to every single other point, so $f(x)$ must go to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following illustration might clarify the limit concept for a one variable function.
[image: Limit of a function]

So as $x$ gets closer to $a$, $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$